# Ecto conditional validation if couple of fields present

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to implement some validation for the model only if couple of fields present for the model.

Like that:

```
if Changeset.get_field(changeset, :field_a) or Changeset.get_field(changeset, :field_b) do
  changeset
  |> a_lot_of_validations
else
  changeset
end
```

The problem is: when `field_a` or `field_b` present, they returns `string`, so argument error is raised here, becauase

```
"string" or "string"
```

returns argumenterror in elixir. Implement `not(is_nil(get_field))` make the line length so long (it's even long right now), so I'm curious about clean way of implementing this conditional validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `not(is_nil(_))` and `or`, you can just use `||` which treats `nil` and `false` as falsy and everything else as truthy as `Ecto.Changeset.get_field` will never return `false` for a string field:

```
if Changeset.get_field(changeset, :field_a) || Changeset.get_field(changeset, :field_b) do
  changeset
  |> a_lot_of_validations
else
  changeset
end
```

If you have `Ecto.Changeset` already imported (they are imported by default in Phoenix models), you can remove `Changeset.`:

```
if get_field(changeset, :field_a) || get_field(changeset, :field_b) do
  changeset
  |> a_lot_of_validations
else
  changeset
end
```

Comment: I haven't knewn this `||` vs `or` specificity before. Thanks!